# How to add scroll in taurus reporting console view so that full details will be displayed

Tags: jmeter, taurus

Am executing my JMeter test script with Taurus reporting tool. I have a number of HTTP requests which are not visible on the reporting because of the fixed space. How i can add a scroll so that all the details are visible. PFA

Thanks [Not showing details fully in the report because of the screen size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppdSd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Taurus documentation](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ConsoleReporter/):

> On Windows, Console Screen is shown in separate window and users may change font size by holding Ctrl key and using mouse wheel. Two additional options are `dummy-cols` and `dummy-rows`, they affect the size of *dummy* screen that is used by dummy screen.

So you can zoom in and out by holding Control key and scrolling the mouse wheel forth/back or provide the `dummy-rows` property value with the desired screen height like:

```
bzt -o modules.console.dummy-rows=150 ....
```

More information [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus/)